# How to set TabIndex in Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabindex

I am new to WPF, I dont know how to do this.
I tried following code -

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding Path=CanCreate, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
     <Hyperlink KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" Command="{Binding Path=CreateCommand}">Create 
         <Hyperlink.Style>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                 <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CanCreate, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </Hyperlink.Style>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Visibility depends on CanCreate Dependency property. Here IsTabStop is not enabling. Can anyone suggest the solution. Thanks in advance.

**Requirement**

I want to set TabIndex to hyperlink when it is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a converter in the `DataTrigger` change your `Hyperlink.Style` to:

```
<Hyperlink.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CanCreate}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
</Hyperlink.Style>
```

**EDIT:** You may also want to remove focus when your `TextBlock` and `Hyperlink` is invisible, you can do it by adding another `DataTrigger`:

```
<Hyperlink.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CanCreate}" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CanCreate}" Value="False">
                          <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
    </Hyperlink.Style>
```

Comment: @RahulTaneja, You need the converter in setting the `Visibility` of `TextBlock`, but as I said above you wont need it in the `DataTrigger`